# Is it possible to substitute a server backend using Dropbox?

Tags: ios, xcode, server, dropbox

I am developing an iOS application (to be deployed on the App Store) that requires content updates on a weekly basis.

I understand that the best way to achieve this would be to use a server, where the app would query for new data and download responses in JSON. However I am not knowledgeable when it comes to HTML, PHP or MySQL and therefore am endeavoring to find an alternative.

Here's an idea: using Dropbox to substitute for a server backend. My app connects to one central Dropbox account, checks for new files, and downloads them if present.

Is this idea feasible? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: there are many "backend substitution services", take a look to this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox cannot be a dependable substitute for your server/backend for following reasons:

1. Dropbox uses OAuth for authentication, which needs user interaction. You do not want your app users to go through Dropbox authentication with your 'common' credentials.
2. Users who have a Dropbox account or the app installed, will most likely use their own credentials to login which completely breaks your flow.
3. Drobox, although a good way of sharing and syncing files is not meant for more meaningful data like web services etc or user/database interaction etc. Just syncing JSON file may suffice your app's needs for now but from a long term perspective you want a proper back end.

As suggested in the comment by @tkanzakic you can [use one of the substitution services](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more) if you don't want to get too technical on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty late to the party, but this is possible and not necessarily a stupid idea (though this depends on what you need). You might want to have a look at [remote storage](https://remotestorage.io/) for example, which allows you to use Dropbox among other providers as backend.

Answer (score -1):

For sure, you can use the **Dropbox Sync API** to achieve this (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync).